# Angular 4 Filtering Table

Tags: angular

I have a table with ID column like this,

ID
1
2
3
4
5

When I key in value of 1, it displayed:
ID
1

But when I key in value of 1, 3, it did not display anything.

Anyone can help me on this problem? Thank you.

This is my filtering code:

```
textFiltering(field: string, $event) {
if ($event.value) {
  const value = $event.value;

  this.source = this._master.filter(record => {
    return record[field].toUpperCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
  });
} else {
  this.source = this._master;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are passing 1,3 you need to split the string into array [1,3] and use **`array.includes`** to check whether elements present inside the array.

Comment: I still have same problem with it.

Comment: textFiltering(field: string, $event): void {
    if ($event.value) {
      const text = $event.value.toString();
      const value = text.split(',');

      this.source = this._master.filter(record => {
        return record[field].toUpperCase().includes(value);
      });
    } else {
      this.source = this._master;
    }
  }